# Can I restart Previous Activity with current Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I know the way to restart current Activity, we do is

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

but in my case, my settings is in the Settings Activity, if i change the settings and then go back to MainActivity the settings are not applied, I have to restart my app. So, In this case the best way is to restart Activity? Am I right? or there's another way? Suggest me the best way. Thanks!!

Comment: how do you start current activity from previous activity?

Comment: Intent intent=new Intent(currentActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent)

Comment: The "standard" Android way would be to read the settings in the `onStart()` callback of your `MainActivity` and make the changes there.

Comment: use `startActivity(intent);` and then `finish();`

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer yes, Absolutely, I will call on onStart() but for example if the  user change language from settings then comes backs to previous activity does the onStart() calls and change settings for them?

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer ya, its working but Toolbar menu drop down menu item language aren't change why?

Comment: Why my question is down voted?Although It's not dublicate

Comment: @Queendevelopers created and answer that I hope covers your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your settings in the `onStart` callback of the Activity, and show the appropriate UI.

To update the Toolbar, call [invalidateOptionsMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) or [supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()) if you're using the support lib. This will trigger a call to `onCreateOptionsMenu()` where you can figure out what to show for the user's current settings.

Comment: Best, Thank you theFunkyEngineer, Worked like a charm. Where did you guys study these things from? Sometimes I got surprised from you guys..